# How to ignore double quotes character in ppython string (as an input argument to a function"

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I need to pass an argument to a function where the certain part of the input needs to be wrapped in double quotes so is then properly interpreted.

The goal is that the string provided by user:
input =  "a-b-c"-d
is intepreted as:
""a-b-c"-d"

Why?
Because between " " you provide an expression where - is treated as a dash and not arithmetical minus.
I need that to pass it finally as
"\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d"

I did try

```
r""a-b-c"-d"
```

but no luck.
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: `r"""\"a-b-c\"-d"""`? If you need more backslashes just add them, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/dfuijo).

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for? If the user inputs ``"a-b-c"-d ``, then it is already interpreted as the string literal ``'"a-b-c"-d'`` – ``""a-b-c"-d"`` doesn't make sense. Do you actually need the outer ``"`` or is that just from not knowing about ``'``? When you say you need to 'pass it finally as "\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d"', do you mean the string *printed* as ``\"a-b-c\"-d``, ``\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d`` or ``"\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d"``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for your input. User input is "a-b-c"-d  and need to be send to another function as a payload in a form "\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d"

Comment: So assuming standard literal syntax, you want to expand ``'"a-b-c"-d'`` to ``'\\"a-b-c\\"-d'`` (i.e. put a literal ``\`` in front of every ``"``)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi to be precise the final string needs to contain three "\" before each double quote.

Comment: I feel we are going in cycles here. Do you need three *literal* ``\`` before each ``"`` or an escaped ``\`` before each ``"``? So are you looking for ``r'\"a-b-c\"-d'`` or ``r'\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d'``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the final string should be  '\\\"a-b-c\\\"-d'

Answer (score -1):

Please Try '""a-b-c"-d"'

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your function name is `func()`, then in order to avoid this kind of problem, simply call the function like `func(' "a-b-c"-d')`. So logic is that instead of using `"`, simply use `'`

Answer (score -1):

You can define the String with ' '
for example:

```
input = '"a-b-c"-d'
```

another way is to put \ before the ".

```
for example:
    input = "\"b\""
    print(input)
```

will print "b"